# numbers that are the difference of two integers that have an odd number of divisors

Tags: number-theory

[image]

This is a pre rmo problem........ the answer to this question is 3..... i.e. nos. 1512, 1511, 1510. I believe... x and y are perfect squares... as odd divisors.... but in that way more than 3 nos. Can be expressesd as difference of 2 squares. For e.g. 11(121-100).

Comment: Try a more descriptive title. No one is going to help you.

Comment: Atleast  u help bro

Comment: Lemma: a number has an odd number of of divisors if and only if it is a perfect square.  Hence set containsc: 3,8,15,24,.....,n^2 -1,...,1935,5,12,.....,n^2-4,...,1932,7..., etc. way,way,way, more than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and the published answer is wrong.  Any difference of squares satisfies the condition. $5=9-4$ satisfies it nicely.  If $x=a^2, y=b^2$ given any $n$ we can try to say $n=a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and note that the parities of $a+b$ and $a-b$ are the same, so we can do this as long as $n$ does not have exactly one factor of $2$, or is not of the form $4k+2$.